# Determinants of matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix

I was given the task to make an algorithm that will take as input parameter square matrix and check the regularity of the matrix (counting the corresponding determinant). Output parameters need to be regular and determinant.

One of the matrix (5X5) looks like:

```
10   1   7 0.5 -0.5
 2   7   1   1    1
 5   3  12   2   -1
 3   2   1   8  0.2
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.2    1
```

I made a program in python. But when I enter the matrix drop me wrong determinants. So now I wonder what's wrong.

This is my program:

```
from numpy import *
print "Zadaj dimenziju matrice"
a=[]
n=input ("Red matrice: ")
for i in range (n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range (n):
        r=raw_input("Unesite element a["+str(i+1)+"]["+str(j+1)+"] element: ")
        a[i].append(r)
M=array(a)

print M

def rem(TT):
    d=TT.shape
    r=[]
    for i in range(d[0]):
        r.append([])
        for j in range(d[0]):
            if i==0:
                continue
            elif j==n:
                continue
            else:
                r[i].append(TT[i][j])
    r.pop(0)          
    return array(r)

def det (MM):
    b=0
    d=MM.shape
    if d==(1,1):
        return MM[0][0]
    else:
        for j in range (d[0]):
            global n
            n=j
            k=float(MM[0][j])
            kk=float(det(rem(MM)))
            s=k*kk
            b=b+((-1)**(j))*int(s)
    return b

print "Determinanta je: ", det(M)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using numpy so you could use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) linear algebra [tools](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html) as well.

This an example using your matrix:

```
import numpy
M = numpy.matrix([[10,1,7,0.5,-0.5],[2,7,1,1,1],[5,3,12,2,-1],[3,2,1,8,0.2],[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,1]])
mDet = numpy.linalg.det(M)
```

You can use it in your code just deleting your determinant function and adding this line at the beginning of your code:

```
from numpy.linalg import det
```

You just have to call `det`. Your code would be something like:

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import det

print "Zadaj dimenziju matrice"
a=[]
n=input ("Red matrice: ")
for i in range (n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range (n):
        r=raw_input("Unesite element a["+str(i+1)+"]["+str(j+1)+"] element: ")
        a[i].append(r)
M=array(a)

print M

print "Determinanta je: ", det(M)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have to make an algorithm that for any matrix that you enter is calculated determinant. I can not define a matrix in the code. I have to enter the matrix when the program starts.

Comment: @martugnc My answer contains just an example, I suggested you to use `numpy.linalg.det` instead your own determinant funcion. I'll include it in an edit of my answer.

Comment: Does not work, when I enter the matrix expel me the solution zero.

Comment: @martugnc I have just run the code I posted in my last edit and with your input matrix I got:  `4614.08`. I used the same data as input for  octave (free implementation of matlab) and got `4614.1` The difference is the result of different precisions used in each program.

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
matrix=[]
def det(IC,i):
    global matrix,row
    determinent=0
    m=1
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        if j not in IC:
            m+=1
            if i == row-1:
                determinent = matrix[i][j]
            else:
                determinent+=(-1)**(m)*matrix[i][j]*det(IC+[j],i+1)
    return determinent
row=int(input("enter order"))
for i in range(row):
    rowEntry=[int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]

    matrix.append(rowEntry)
print(matrix)
print(det([],0))
```